# AngularJs displaying ng-repeat data with some conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

This is my JSON object response:

```
{
"senderdata": "123456789",
"senderName": "ifelse",
"message": "Hi",
"draftName": "empty"
}
```

I am displaying this in UI using `ng-repeat`:

I am getting this json response in $scope.drafts.

my code:

```
tr(ng-repeat='draft in drafts')
 td {{draft.draftName}}
 td {{draft.senderName}}
 td {{draft.message}}
```

But I need some condition,

if my draftName object key have string called **"empty"** I don't want to display data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juse use  **`!=`** condition with ng-if

```
tr(ng-repeat='draft in drafts' ng-if="draft.draftName !== 'empty'")
```

Comment: Sorry if empty i dont want to display datas.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your ng-repeat by draft name to display items only when draftName is not empty

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:{ draftName: '!empty'}">
  {{item.senderName}}-{{item.senderdata}}-{{item.draftName}}
</div>
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LIGR0Y4kol87NOcXGY9V?p=preview)